# ID человека, предложившего пост ВК

Tags: jquery, json, vkontakte-api

[Пример запроса api.vk](https://vk.com/dev/wall.get?params[owner_id]=-31112617&params[offset]=1&params[count]=1&params[filter]=owner&params[extended]=0&params[v]=5.73)
Необходимо достать из JSON значение signer_id.

```
$(document).ready(loadPhoto);

function getUrl(method, params){
    if (!method) throw new Error('Не указан метод')
    params = params || {};
    params['access_token'] = 'здесь был токен'
    return 'https://api.vk.com/method/' + method + '?' + $.param(params);
}


function sendRequest(method, params, func){
    $.ajax({
        url: getUrl(method, params),
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSONP',
        success: func
        });
}


function loadPhoto() {
    sendRequest('wall.get', {owner_id: '-31112617', offset: 1}, function(data) {
        drawPhoto(data.response);
    });
}

function drawPhoto(items){
    var html = '';

    for (var i = 1; i < items.length; i++){
        var f = items[i];

        html += '<li>' + '<a target="_blank" href="vk.com/id'+ signer_id + '>' + '</li>';
    }
}
```

На последней строке попытался обратится, но консоль выдает ошибку signer_id is not difined. 
 You don't say??
 Подскажите, как реализовать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну по идее все json значения находятся у Вас в `f` во время прохождения цикла предположу что `f.signer_id`, а так надо смотреть структуру json файла. Просто при обращении к `signer_id` Вы обращаетесь к "левой" переменной нигде не определённой, в результате и возникает данная ошибка.
Попробуйте обратиться к `console.log(items)` и найти данный параметр и копировать путь к нему.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, верно предположили.